# Finding directions for Bus + bike

Tags: bikeroutes, software

Buses in my city have bike racks. In some cases, it is faster to use both the bus and your bike to get from point A to point B (the transit system here isn't too good). Google Maps is great for finding transit directions, or bike directions, but as far as I know, I cannot easily find directions that make use of both... 
Are there any tools/websites that would help me finding such information?

Comment: Answers to this question might be too dependent on where you live. For example, in Seattle, you can get that routing info from the RTA website. But it won't help someone in Portland...

Comment: Here's a google maps feature request. Upvote the feature request if you think it's a good idea: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/tydzPgFU4js;context-place=forum/maps

Answer (score 3):

[OpenTripPlanner](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki) will do this, but isn't everywhere yet.  There are deployments for [New York City](http://demo.opentripplanner.org/), [Portland, OR](http://rtp.trimet.org/#/), and a [few other cities](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/Demos).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: No. Google Maps will, when you're in "transit" mode, tell you to walk to the train station/bus stop, but bike/transit trips seems to be beyond it for now. There are no other directions systems I'm aware of that will do this.

[image]

Longer answer:

You'll have to set up your route as multiple trips. (I did this when setting up my bike/train commute that involved, depending on when I got to Newark Penn Station in the morning, either three trains and two bike trips, or two trains and a bus and two bike trips, or three bike trips and two trains.) What you *can* do to make all this easier is to bookmark the locations of transit stops you'll be using often, as well as destinations.

In the above picture, you'll see that Newark Penn Station has a star on it. That's because I have it bookmarked in Google Maps. Click on any destination or building or landmark on the map, and you can do this. It'll then show up on the map as a star, for easier mapping.